# running testNG xml via cmd prompt

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

my test NG jar is in C:\TestNG\testng.jar,'
testNG xml : `D:\auto\auto\testng.xml`
java classes: `D:\auto\auto\src\CloudPlatform\*`

selenium: ;C:\Users\muthus\Downloads\selenium-java-2.43.1\selenium-2.43.1\selenium-2.43.1.jar

Ive set classpath as : `C:\TestNG\testng-5.5.jar;C:\Users\muthus\Downloads\selenium-java-2.43.1\selenium-2.43.1\selenium-2.43.1.jar;D:\auto\auto\src\CloudPlatform\*`

Am unable to run it via cmd prompt with the below issue:

```
D:\auto\auto>java -cp C:\TestNG\testng-5.5.jar;D:\auto\auto\src\CloudPlatform\*; 
org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Error:

```
D:\auto\auto>java -cp C:\TestNG\testng-5.5.jar;D:\auto\auto\src\CloudPlatform\*;
 org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException:
No sourcedir was specified
        at org.testng.TestNG.checkConditions(TestNG.java:1170)
        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1010)
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:997)
```

Need your valuable help on this!

Comment: add a space between semicolon and org.testng.TestNG

Comment: @almasshaikh thanks for that...now it shows a diff error :- Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException:
No sourcedir was specified

Comment: Paste your full stacktrace in question please.

Comment: @almasshaikh have edited the full error

Comment: explicitely specify the test source directory using -sourcedir see [this](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestNG.html)

Comment: @almasshaikh stil getting the same error : - D:\auto\auto>java -cp C:\TestNG\testng-5.5.jar;D:\auto\auto\src\CloudPlatform\*;
 org.testng.TestNG testng.xml -sourcedir D:\auto\auto\src\CloudPlatform\*
Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException:
No sourcedir was specified
        at org.testng.TestNG.checkConditions(TestNG.java:1170)
        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1010)
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:997)